# MySQL Row or Column

Tags: mysql, sql

In my database currently each user takes up 12 rows each having 3 values/columns.

I could convert it so that each user takes up 1 row but each row would have 25 values. (it's 25 and not 36 because I'd only enter the user_id once)

Would it be more efficient to use 1 row with 25 columns or 12 rows with 3 columns?

Yes, I know 25 < 36 but I'm curious as to how much of a difference this would make?

added information. 12 are var char, 12 are integers (lit. 1-12), 12 are integers(user_ids, which would be reduced 1 if all in 1 row)

More information, the 12 var chars are also editable by the user. Will updating each row take longer to load?

Comment: I am not sure I can even imagine why the schema you have would be desirable. Was there a reason for that? What's wrong with 36 rows - if you *truly* need all that information?

Comment: The best approach depends on what this data actually is. In any case for 25 (or 36) values, you don't really need a database.

Comment: Depends on the data: Table design is about relationships.  If all data relates to each other exactly one to one, then one row makes sense.  but if those columns contain specific names to roles allowed within the application, then normalizing the data and having separate tables makes sense.  A user can have many roles a role can belong to many users.  so 3 tables makes sense.  But if you can honestly say now and for the foreseeable future that each column value ties only to a user ID once, and you don't have to add structure (new roles) to accommodate, then 1 row makes sense... clear as mud?

Comment: Go for the 1 row 25 cols, no questions asked...

Comment: Don't worry about efficiency.  Worry about what is most correct, what is most maintainable and readable.

Comment: @AndrewBarber, It's a user library with multiple sections. This was the best/most efficient  way I could think up.

Comment: Without understanding the data, how this data relates to the other data, the mid/long term of potential changes to structure, it's difficult to postulate a valid response to this question.  1 row 25 columns may be correct, X tables with X columns may be more correct. Again it's about relationships and scaling and support.  It's what's "Correct" as Andy puts it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of normalization, one row with 25 columns.

Comment: yes you would want one row with multiple columns and only one id for that user

Comment: I'd disagree.  It really depends on the data.  If all the data is one to one relationship to the user then maybe.  If data can be combined into similar constructs (say roles) then normalization wouldn't be one row.  so the type of column, the data it represents really matters here.

Comment: Well normalized, it would be one record per user. That record might have only a few fields and some other tables (perhaps a role table) might need to be made, but one record per user.

Comment: the key here is to follow normalization. one id per user per table.. if it needs to be multiple tables depending on what the data is then so be it